# How can I submit the values of one of many auto generated forms

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a table with many auto generated forms (there could literally be hundreds of forms). The code for that is php based and looks like this:

```
$cellPosition = 0;
$rowCounter = 1;
$infoCounter = 1;

for ($x=0;$x <= count($assetName);$x++)
{
    for ($i=0;$i < count($currentJobs);$i++)
    {
        $rowCounter= 1;
        if ($currentJobs[$i][0] == $table->getCellContents(0,$x))
        {

            for ($y =0; $y < $currentJobs[$i][10];$y++)
            {
                $rowCounter++;
            }
            $table->setCellAttributes ($rowCounter,$cellPosition,"id='jobCell' bgcolor = ". $currentJobs[$i][4].  " rowspan=" . $currentJobs[$i][9]);
            $table->setCellContents($rowCounter++,$cellPosition,
                                    "<form id='scheduleForm".$infoCounter++."' method='POST' action='../forms/updateJobForm.php'>".
                                    "<input type='hidden' name='jobInfo' value='" . $currentJobs[$i][1] . "'/>" . " " . "Job# (".$currentJobs[$i][2] . ")<br>" . $currentJobs[$i][3] .
                                    "</form>");
        }
            else
            {
                $rowCounter = 1;
            }
    }
    $cellPosition++;
}
echo $table->display();
```

I have the jobCell (a td element) bound to the following javascript/jquery code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#jobCell").click(function()
        {
            $(this).children('form').submit();
            //$('#scheduleForm').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I each jobcell is click-able and I previously had it to where clicking anyone would submit the form. The problem is that it would only send the information for the hidden information for the last jobcell in the table. Now with my current code, it only allows the user to click the first cell and it does submit. How accomplish submitting the hidden data in the jobcell that is clicked when I have many forms?

Comment: it would help if you could show a demo/sample, just take the final generated html and paste it on jsfiddle...

Comment: Posted on jsfiddle at [link](http://jsfiddle.net/K9sRf/). Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should only ever be one of each ID on the page. You have you have lots of forms all with the same ID it may well only submit the last. Change id to class, there can be any elements on the same page with the same class.

At a guess something like this. But without seeing your actual HTML output this could be wrong.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#jobCell").click(function()
        {
            $(this).children('form').submit();
            //$('.scheduleForm').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I think he is better off using the class name since there are more than one element with id "jobcell"... just a suggestion

Comment: You were correct! Once I switched the id to class, it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check that `id='jobCell'` is only set once.

I would expect the code to look more like the form id code:

```
id='scheduleForm".$infoCounter++."'
```

Comment: I had the same idea, but with the same results.

Comment: You would also need to change the Jquery selector to something like this: `$("[id^='jobCell']").click(function()`